# wiring up new air mover

Tags: electrical, hvac

I have a central air system and my squirrel cage fan inside the house started humming and then stopped. I figured it was the capacitor but I found a whole new fan for just a little more. Im having trouble wiring it up because there is 4 more wires than the old one and the old one only had one of the multi speed wires hooked  up. The common was orange but on the diagram to the box and on the fan shroud is a different color. I got it hooked up and it turns on with the thermostat but than turns off and the motor is hot. What am I missing.

Comment: We need pics and detailed model numbers for both the previous and new units.  You are in trouble here. The motor overload probably cut out due to incorrect wiring.   This is a place where you really really need know what you are doing. No experimentation allowed!

Comment: Can you post photos of the label on the new motor and of the wiring diagram for the air handler/furnace?

Comment: I will as soon as I can figure out how to resize the pictures. Also I know no experimenting. I have been diy my own everything for years. Now unfortunately I am a cancer patient and meds are killing finances so I have to do this myself

Comment: @JC we need information on the motor. Tell us the type of motor brand horsepower and frame , model , wire colors. We can help but you have not provided enough information. You may not be able to provide a photo but you can type so get us that info and we can probably help you out.